# PHP Website facebook login

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, authentication

I am working on a social website, and I want to integrate facebook login in it. But I need advice on the following;

- Visitors can register on the website and login with the information they registered with.
- Registered visitors can log in and create and save 'documents(plain text in online texteditor)', send requests to other users to rate their 'documents' and receive and send private messages.

I know how to do the above, but what if I want visitors to be able to use their facebook accounts to do the above, is that possible? I already know that I will be using a mysql database to save registered user accounts and their documents and private message.

And if it is, can you advice me on how to do this?

I know it sounds a little vague at the moment, but I can not tell more about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the develiper center at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/getting-started/ or  try the alternative http://opauth.org/

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for "Facebook Login". Head over to [FBs developer center](https://developers.facebook.com/) and read the documentation on "[Login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/)". It covers everything you need to implement what you want.